# Convert a given SQL query into linq for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Can someone help me to convert the below SQL query to Linq? I tried so many methods none of them are worked.

```
SELECT PM.Name, SUM(CO.TotalPrice) 
FROM CustomerOrder CO, PaymentMethod PM 
WHERE CO.PaymentID = PM.PaymentID 
  AND CO.Status = 'CL' 
GROUP BY PM.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really straightforward.  You just need a Navigation Property on CustomerOrder for PaymentMethod, and then you translate the `group by` and `select`, something like this:

```
select PM.Name,SUM(CO.TotalPrice) 
from CustomerOrder CO, PaymentMethod PM 
where CO.PaymentID=PM.PaymentID 
and CO.Status='CL' 
group by PM.Name
```

becomes

```
from o in db.CustomerOrder
where o.Status == 'CL'
group o by o.PaymentStatus.Name into g
select new { PaymentStatus = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(o => o.TotalPrice) };
```